# MySQL/PHP Order By Where

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I have the following query -

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test where admin = 'Yes' order by name = '$_GET[name]' DESC");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
   $id.=$row[id];
}

echo $id;
```

I want a list of id's starting from the id of the $_GET[name] however it's returning a list with a start name of the row underneath? Any idea's?

Many Thanks.

Comment: Please, provide a data set and what result you're getting/what you want. Your code is also vulnerable to SQL injection. Your API is deprecated. All around poor, poor code.

Comment: Woah! You need to seriously check the security of your code. Not only are you using a deprecated library (`mysql_*`), but your code is seriously vulnerable to SQL injection!

Answer (score 1):

1. Use an array
2. You need to use quotes around colums names

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test where admin = 'Yes' order by name = '$_GET[name]' DESC");

$ids = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
   $ids[] =$row['id'];
}

// Your IDs are now in an array which is easier to work with
print_r($ids);
```

FYI, [you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

You're also wide open to [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174)